# Real time image processing from webcam stream

Tags: real-time, webcam, google-colaboratory

I would like to feed images from my webcam into a neural net. I found piece of code that allow me to take snapshots from my webcam. But they all require some user interaction and save the image every time to disk. Is it possible to read a webcam image without saving to disk?

One of the examples provides "webcam snapshot" funcionality. https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=2viqYx97hPMi

I also tried a Jupyter Notebook specific solution for webcam streaming https://github.com/maartenbreddels/ipywebrtc but it doesn't work in Colab.